# Why is my javascript regexp test function not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a Javascript function that tests a regexp that I'm intending to validate positive decimals up to a precision of two:

```js
function isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo(str) {
    return /^\d*(\.\d{1,2}$)?/.test(str);
}
```

I'm not getting the results I'm expecting when I call it from code.

For example:

```js
var a = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1");         //   expect t, returns t
var b = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1.2");       //   expect t, returns t
var c = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1.25");      //   expect t, returns t
var d = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1.257");     // * expect f, returns t *
var e = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1.2575");    // * expect f, returns t *
var f = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo(".25");       // * expect t, returns f *
var g = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("d");         //   expect f, returns f
var h = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("d1");        //   expect f, returns f
var i = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1d");        // * expect f, returns t *
var j = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("1d1");       // * expect f, returns t *
var k = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("-1");        //   expect f, returns f
var l = isPositiveDecimalPrecisionTwo("-1.5");      //   expect f, returns f
```

There are three issues:

1. Validating "1.257" or "1.2575" returns true, which I though would
   return false due to the `\d{1,2}`
2. Validating ".25" returns false, which I thought would return true due to the `^\d*`
3. Validating "1d" or "1d1" return true. It looks like `\.` is reading as any character when it looks to me like it's a properly escaped "." (dot).

However, when I use a tool like regexpal.com, the same regexp appears to be validating the way I expect:

> http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%5Cd%2B(%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%24)%3F&input=

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `$` is inside the parenthesis.  You want it to be *after* the group.

```
/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

This should work the way you expect.

With the `$` inside, it was matching everything that started with a number, since the end of string (`$`) was "optional".

Comment: I want to +1, but there's something wrong here . . . the regex that the OP posted will actually match any string, *whether or not* it begins with a digit (because of the `*`). Your fix is right, your explanation is right, but something is just *missing*.

Comment: @ruakh: The OP's original regex will not match `-1`.  The regex will match 0 numbers, and then 0 of the group, so it will match "nothing".

Comment: Re: second sentence: Right, but regexes are *allowed* to match "nothing". All of his examples return `true`, at least in Firefox.

Comment: @ruakh: Weird.  `/^\d*(\.\d{1,2}$)?/.test('-1')` says `true` in Chrome and Firefox, but [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%5Cd*(%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%24)%3F&input=-1) says otherwise.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like RegexPal doesn't actually give any indication of *whether* a regex matches, only of *what* it matches; so when the regex matches "nothing", you don't see it.

Comment: @ruakh: I actually just figured that out.  I asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13383142/206403), and then when I thought about it, I realized what was going on.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @ruakh: You're right about RegexPal. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without grouping the decimal portion by just adding a `?` after the escaped decimal point

```
^\d*\.?\d{1,2}$
```