# RegexPal differs from browsers

Tags: javascript, regex

I was answering a [question about regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13381596/206403), when I noticed something weird.  I was testing regexes in [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/), and I was getting different results from what Chrome and Firefox were telling me.

The regex in question is: `/^\d*(\.\d{1,2}$)?/`.

In Firefox and Chrome: `/^\d*(\.\d{1,2}$)?/.test('-1')` returns `true`, but RegexPal says it doesn't match.

> http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=%5E%5Cd%2A(%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%24)%3F&input=-1

My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the regex matches nothing, by which I mean the empty string.

The regex matches the start of the string, then 0 numbers, then 0 of the group, so it would "match" `-1`, as it fits that mold, but the "match" would be "nothing" (empty string).

Why does RegexPal say it doesn't match, but my web browsers say it does?

Comment: That regex should match literally anything (you're making `\d` optional and the whole group optional as well). It looks like a bug in RegexPal to me.

Comment: Wait.  I just thought of something.  RegexPal "highlights" matches.  So, it tries to highlight the match.  Which is an empty string, so you can't see it.  I knew that X_X

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there like a fake pony generator or something? Or did you draw that avatar yourself?

Comment: @NullUserException: I wish I drew that by myself.  There's a pony creator, that I used to make it :-)  It's over here: http://generalzoi.deviantart.com/art/Pony-Creator-Full-Version-254295904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegexPal is working, but it's just not obvious.  The regex matches the empty string, so RegexPal highlights that for you.

Well, since the empty string is empty, you can't see that it's highlighting it.